# Are there any security concerns with allowing developers run hidden WebBrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, security, internet-explorer

Assuming I allow developers to open any URL (local or remote) in a hidden web browser and the developers can only receive common events from the web browser such as: document complete, before navigate, navigate error etc..

Are there any security concerns I'm not aware of ?
I think the same-origin security policy covers my concerns, However, it's always good to consult with other and hear out other's concerns.

BTW
I need this mechanism in some cases to detect if a user is logged in by navigating to the login page and intercept page redirection to success URL (I Wouldn't want to open a popup for 1 sec and then close it right away).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will encounter cross-domain restrictions. Other than that, the framed page can easily direct the user to another site, eg:

```
<script>
if(top != self) top.location.href = this.location.href;
</script>
```

Well, that's just of an annoyance for you. But consider:

```
<script>
if(top != self) top.location.href = "http://evilsite.com/getviruses/";
</script>
```